# How to get values of a multiselect Listbox in order they were clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a multiselect Listbox and fetching the list of selected values using

```
$('[id*=ListBox]').click(function(){

    var selectedItems = $(this).val();
    var lastItem = $("[id*=ListBox] option:selected").last().val();

});
```

This returns me comma separated array of selected values. But the problem is the array is always **sorted** by values and not generated by order in which selected values were clicked.

**3000 , 3005 , 3009 , 3011**

But if I first click item with value 3011, then 3005 , then 3000 and last 3009 I want values in that order

**3011 , 3005 ,3000 , 3009**

How to get selected values in order in which they were clicked ?

**EDIT**

Getting the most recent value selected also solves my problem.

How to get most recent selected item ?

Comment: can you add a demo ?

Comment: Getting the most recent value selected also solves my problem.How to get most recent selected item ?

Comment: You can keep a hidden input and on click event set the value in the hidden field to latest value.

Comment: So in example above I am clicking on item with value 3009 . How to get 3009 value

Comment: Can include `html` at Question ?

Comment: But `$(this).val()` gives me all selected items , not most recent one that I should put in hidden field

Comment: $('[id*=ListBox] option').click() is not firing on Internet Explorer . Can anybody tell how to call it  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what worked for me . I had to take a global array and after each click compare selected items of listbox with elements in array . The difference between them gave me latest selected item .

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            var arr = [];
            $("[id*=listBox]").click(function () {
                var lastItem = '';
                var selArr = [];
                var flag = 0;

                selArr = $(this).val();
               // alert(selArr);
                if ( $(this).val()!=null) {
                    if ($(this).val().length > 2) {

                        lastItem = $(selArr).not(arr).get();

                        selArr = $.grep(selArr, function (value) {
                            return value != lastItem;
                        });
                        flag = 1;
                        //arr = [];
                    }
                }
                arr = selArr;
                $(this).val(selArr);

                if (flag == 1)
                    alert("Cannot select more than 2 items");

            });
        });
```

This question made me discover two strange things .

1. `$("#Listbox option").click()` doesn't fire on Internet explorer ( i used version 9 ) but
   works fine on others . I don't know why option element in not
   fetched in IE.
2. `$(#Listbox).val()` gives comma seprated list of selected values in
   sorted order and not in order in which the items were selected. This
   proved to be a major surprise and headache .

Answer (score 1):

First, set an event that adds an integer to each listbox item whenever the user clicks. Store the integer in a hidden element somewhere on the page, or do something clever by setting a data-attribute on the element like this:

```
$(function() {
    $("#ListBox").data("selected-index", 0);
});

$("#ListBox option").on("click", function() {
    var currentSelectedIndex = $("#ListBox").data("selected-index");
    $(this).data("counter", currentSelectedIndex++);
});
```

Then in order to get all those in the order they've been clicked:

```
function getOrderOfItems() {
    var arrayOfSelected = new Array(),

    // Use Math and .map() to get the highest data-counter:

    counters = $("#ListBox option[data-counter]").map(function() {
        return parseInt($(this).data("counter"), 10);
    }).get();

    var highestCounter = Math.max.apply(Math, counters);

    // We have the highest counter, so use a for loop to select the selected options.
    for (var i = 0; i < highestCounter; i++) {
        arrayOfSelected.push($("#ListBox option[data-counter=" + i + "]"));
    }

    console.log(arrayOfSelected);
    return arrayOfSelected;
}
```

Where arrayOfSelected contains the ListBox items in the order they were clicked.

Answer (score 1):

Note, `html` from @PaulRoub 's Answer used , as no `html` appear at OP

If interpret Question correctly , try substituting `change` event for `click` event ; creating an array of selected values , utilize `.slice(-2)[0]` to view previously selected item .

```js
$("#ListBox").data("prev", []).change(function(e) {
  $(this).data().prev.push(this.value)
  console.log($(this).data().prev.slice(-2)[0], // last selected item
      $(this).data().prev) // array of selected items , in order selected
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<select id="ListBox" multiple>
  <option value="3000">3000</option>
  <option value="3001">3001</option>
  <option value="3002">3002</option>
  <option value="3003">3003</option>
  <option value="3004">3004</option>
</select>
```