# Appending text to variable always results in same order

Tags: javascript

I have a multiselect and every time a change event happens I want the values of the selected items div to be appending to body of text. I'm using a forEach loop to run an ajax request and the response each time gets set to the body of text (in this case is a textarea). It doesn't seem to matter if I select in the order `section 1` then `section 2` or `section 2` then `section 1` the two sections are always in the same order. (section 2 on top of section 1).

In this case the values are parts of a letter. So its always the body of the letter on top of the intro, which obviously is the opposite of what I want.

I thought the problem was the command I was using to set the textarea value but I changed by code to just add the sections to a variable like `body += section`(in the forEach) and `console.log` it. The same thing happens.

Here is my code:

```
$('#my-select').change(function() {

    //empties the textarea 
    tinymce.get('elm1').setContent("");

    //Array of the selected values
    let codes = $('#my-select').val();

    codes.forEach(function(code) {
      
      let data = {
        action: 'getSectionByCode',
        code: code
      }
      //returns an object
      let sections = $.parseJSON($.ajax({
          url:  '/modules/ajax/ajax_handler.php',
          type: "POST",
          data:data,
          async: false
      }).responseText);

      //Set the contents of the editor to be section.body
      tinymce.get("elm1").execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, sections.body);
      //Alternative tried
      //body += sections.body

    })

  });
```

[image: Scenario 1]

[image: Senario 2]

So in each picture, the sections on the right of the multiselect are in 2 different orders, but the content on the left is the same

The bold text is where `start of letter` begins. So in each picture it is at the bottom

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot?

Comment: Or a reproducible example on codesandbox/codepen/jsfiddle would be much appreciated

Comment: @TasosBu I have edited it with screenshots

Comment: I believe the problem is the t mceInsertContent method. It sais that it "Inserts content at caret position". Have you tried `setContent()` with `prevContent + newContent`?

Comment: @TasosBu I thought that was the problem too. But like I said if i dont use the tinymce and just assign the `sections.body` to a variable, each time it gives the same order. I don't mind if there is a way to set it in the correct order into a variable. Because then I can use the variable

Comment: `$('#my-select').val()` just gets you the selected values, in the order the options have in the select element. This does not preserve the order in which the options where selected, in any way. There _is_ no native way to get them in that order, so if you need it - you will have to implement it yourself. (Compare current selection to previous selection, and try and figure out which option was selected last that way.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get values of a multiselect Listbox in order they were clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32251585/how-to-get-values-of-a-multiselect-listbox-in-order-they-were-clicked)

Comment: @04FS I understand now the issue, but I the plugin im using has an `afterSelect` callback. I'll try do something with that :)

Answer (score -1):

If I understand it correctly, you should be able to sort the `codes` array before the loop to determine the order of the sections.